# Rake не отображает список тасков

Tags: ruby, rake

Делаю обвязки для chef-repo на чистом rake. Последний упорно отказывается
показывать задачи (хотя при начале разработки успешно делал это):

```
# Rakefile

task :dummy do
  puts 'yummy!'
end
```

---

```
bundle exec rake dummy
> yummy!
```

---

```
bundle exec rake -T
# ничего, кроме перевода строки
echo $?
> 0
```

---

```
bundle show rake
> /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А если вот так?

```
desc "Simple task"
task :dummy do
  puts 'yummy!'
end
```

Если нет желания добавлять описание, то

```
rake -AT
```

должен показать все задачи независимо от наличия описания.